# custom phtml file in magento2.1.6 not working

Tags: magento2.1.6

i want to update this file in my custome theme

> magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml

i have add it here in my theme

> magento2\app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml

but its not working. please guide me how to make changes init.

Comment: please let me know if you have issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep your file inside below path,

```
magento2\app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\amount\default.phtml
```

please remove **view\base** folder from your path.